# Show that the average $(X_1+···+X_n)/n$ has the same standard Cauchy distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i. i. d. random variables whose common distribution is standard Cauchy, that is, $P(X_j≤t) =∫^t_{−∞}\frac{dx}{π(1 +x^2)},  t∈R,j= 1,...,n.$ Show that the average $(X_1+···+X_n)/n$ has the same standard Cauchy distribution.  Does this contradict the weak law of large numbers?

My Try:
Honestly I have no clear idea how to start. But here is my try.

$P((X_1+···+X_n)/n≤t)=P((X_1+···+X_n)≤nt)=1-P((X_1+···+X_n)>nt)\geq 1-\frac{1}{n^2t^2}E((X_1+···+X_n)^2)=1-\frac{1}{n^2t^2} \operatorname{Var} (X_1+···+X_n)=1-\frac{1}{n^2t^2}n\operatorname{Var}(X_1) $.

That is all I could do so far. But I am not sure whether I am on the right track. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: First, find the characteristic function of a Cauchy random variable, and then compute characteristic function of the average of the i.i.d Cauchy random variables. As for the second part, I suggest computing the expectation of a Cauchy random variable.

Comment: Thinking about the final question you should discover that it's "off-track" to so much as write down "$Var(X_1)."$

Comment: @KayleoftheCreeks: Thanks. But I don't get how the expectation helps to figure out whether it contradicts. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was incorrect, I meant that you should "compute" the variance of the Cauchy random variable as spaceisdarkgreen suggested and then consider the assumptions of the strong law of large numbers and why it does not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

Characteristic functions swiftly solve the problem:

Let $\phi$ denote the characteristic function of $X_1$. Since the $X_i$ are iid, the characteristic function of $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}n$ is $t\mapsto \phi(\frac tn)^n=\exp(-|t|/n)^n=\exp(-|t|)=\phi(t)$.

Thus, the distribution of $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}n$ is that of $X_1$.

Comment: Can you please explain why $\phi(\frac tn)^n=\exp(-|t|/n)^n$?

Comment: @Derivative: just compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ and apply the inversion theorem.